# Magento2.3.3: How do I share product images between products?

Tags: magento2.3.3

Making configurations is duplicating images 8 times. I would like to share one image across the configuration products.

I read I should look here: [pixelpaul.net/magento-share-images-on-more-products](http://pixelpaul.net/magento-share-images-on-more-products) 
But the link is broken.

I can't believe a simple product with 11 color photos, 4 different sizes, and one other option is going to take up 500MB for each product.